# Can I use Windows Upgrade Offer by using other OEM Windows 7 key?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I have a Dell laptop with a genuine OEM Windows 7.  I don't want to upgrade it. I have purchased a new machine without an OS pre-installed.

Can I use a Windows Upgrade Offer  With the Dell Windows 7 OEM key to install Windows 8 on my new machine?

Answer (score 2):

According [to](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-IN/Home/Faq):

> The upgrade offer is tied to a Windows 7 PC purchased between 2 June 2012 and 31 January 2013, but you can choose to redeem the offer and install the upgrade on any compatible Windows-based PC with a qualifying base operating system

ie your answer is 'No'.